# Inserting HTML into Word via Word.Interop cause different paragraph headers font size

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, office-interop

In one of my program I need to insert some simple htmls into word document at some range, so I use function like that to use for every range I want

```
 public static void AddHtmlTextAtRange(this Range range, string html)
        {
            var tempFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".html");
            var formattedHtml = TextToHtmlPreProcessing(html);
            File.WriteAllText(tempFilename, string.Format("<html> {0} </html>", formattedHtml));

            range.InsertFile(tempFilename, ConfirmConversions:false);

            File.Delete(tempFilename);
        }
```

The problem is that in some cases when I add `html` file at range like that, there are some paragraph header size problems occures.

Seems like it depends of what foes first int file.
If it's header - then number font is bigger.

File example:

```
<html>
    <h2 style=''><span>Document Purpose</span></h2>Some data info<span></span>
    <h2 style=''><span>Scope & Requirements Traceability</span></h2>
    Some data too
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;font-weight: bold; background:#BFBFBF'>Ref</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;font-weight: bold; background:#BFBFBF'>Requirement</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;font-weight: bold; background:#BFBFBF'>Req Met (Y/N)</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;font-weight: bold; background:#BFBFBF'>Action taken</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style='border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h2 style=''><span>Background</span></h2>
    Some info
    <h2 style=''><span>Risks, Assumptions, Issues and Dependencies</span></h2>
    Risks info
</html>
```

Output example:
[image]

Otherwise, if first goes text and after goes header - everything is looks fine.

(Nevermind the text it absolutley random from the top of my head :) )

File example:

```
<html>
    I dont know
    <h2 style=''><span>Test1</span></h2>
    I dont know
    <h2 style=''><span>Test2</span>
    </h2>
    I dont know too
    <h2 style=''><span>Test3</span>
    </h2>
    Some datainfo
    <h2 style=''><span>Test4</span>
    </h2>
    Test
</html>
```

Output example:

[image]

So, the problem is, how to get rid of this first header bigger size problem?

There is sort of workaroud if I will put something like that `<p>&nbsp;</p>` right after beggining but it cause extra new line, which I really dont want to have there.

Maybe there is some opton to turn it off?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue in Word 2010... Could you perhaps upload the .docx-file that you use to insert the html's into? I guess my style definitions are different....

Comment: @Jbjstam oh, you think that it's template problem?
I'm sorry, but I cant share the template atm (also it's .doc not .docx, but I don't think that it makes things different)

Comment: Well, if I were you, I'd just use the work around :) Add a paragraph, then remove it after inserting it.

Comment: @Jbjstam the problem is I can't reach it after I added the file! I mean the range, where I added the file, has only one paragraph and `range.Text` there is null

Comment: Posted an example how you can find and remove the placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you could remove the placeholder "<p>TEMPTEXT</p>"

```
private static void InsertHtml(Word.Range range, string html)
{
    File.WriteAllText("temp.html", html);

    range.InsertFile(Path.GetFullPath("temp.html"), Type.Missing, false);

    //this is the interesting part
    if (range.Find.Execute("TEMPTEXT")) {
        //range now points to only the text TEMPTEXT

        //We make sure to take the entire paragraph
        var paragraph = range.Paragraphs[1];

        //Then we remove the entire paragraph range
        var paragraphRange = paragraph.Range;
        paragraphRange.Delete();
    }
}
```

I obtained the range object like this:

```
var doc = app.ActiveDocument;
var range = doc.StoryRanges[WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory];
range.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```

Comment: It could be that there is `TEMPTEXT` text in file. Maybe use guid instead?

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, but, damn, it's so ugly, I can't stand it haha

Comment: On other hand I got no other options

Comment: Hehe, sorry, it's the best I can do without seeing the file...

Yes, you can use any placeholder you want. Just replace "TEMPTEXT" with something else in both places.

It's quite ugly, yes, but put it in a subroutine and forget it.

Comment: sorry, it take a week for me to forget it (and mark your post as answer) :D

Comment: Don't worry about it! Much better than when it never happens :-)